# c# read hebrew from text file

Tags: c#, unicode, hebrew, unicode-string

I wrote a text file in the Hebrew language . When I present the contents of the file in C # I do not see what I wrote - I understand that it is tied to Unicode , but I do not really understand it . Help , anyone?

```
string mymail = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\mail\mail.txt");

        MessageBox.Show(mymail);
```

This is the result :

��� ����� ��� �� ��������� ������� ���� �� ������

Comment: How did you create mail.txt? From Notepad? Ensure it was saved with a Unicode encoding, not ANSI.

Comment: Thank you very much! its work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Close your file and re-open it, make sure what you typed is actually persisted in your file. Using the default notepad app in Windows will usually default to ASCII so the characters will not be persisted correctly on disk and so it won't be retrieved correctly either.
2. You are missing your encoding, its probably defaulting to ASCII.

   `string mymail = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\mail\mail.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`
   `MessageBox.Show(mymail);`

Answer (score 2):

```
string mymail = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\mail\mail.txt", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")); 
MessageBox.Show(mymail);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? It's normaly considered good form to explain your suggestions/answers. Code only answers can be surprisingly uninformative, even if they are technically correct. A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.