# c# read non English text file and write to ListView

Tags: c#, listview

So i have simple `Text file` with foreign language (Hebrew) that i am read:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(txtFile, Encoding.ASCII);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    try
    {
        string[] str = line.Split(new char[0]);
        string word = str[0];
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    { }
}

file.Close();
```

And i want to add this word into my `ListView`.
the problem is that i only `see ??????`

i try to change this `Encoding.ASCII` into `Unicode` and `UTF8` but i can only see different symbols but not my language.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724294/c-sharp-read-hebrew-from-text-file

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` is clearly incorrect, since Hebrew is not ASCII. Where did the text file come from? Can you share it with us?

Comment: What font is used in your ListView? (By the way, where is the code that adds the word to the ListView?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try and go with the specific Hebrew encoding:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(txtFile, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255"));
```

Also, try to close and re-open the file (as mentioned here: [c# read hebrew from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724294/c-sharp-read-hebrew-from-text-file))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(word);
word= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

What I basically did, is changing the Encoding of the string to UTF8.

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would help a lot in understanding the method you've used and how it works.